# Data flow anomaly: how to do it correct?

Tags: java, android

I am modifying Volley for Android a bit and Findbugs complains about the data flow and I am a bit lost. First the code:

```
String userAgent;
try {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    userAgent = packageName + "/" + info.versionCode; // DD
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    userAgent = "volley/0";
}

HttpStack stack;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
    stack = new HurlStack();
} else {
    stack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
}
```

So I thought that findbugs would differ between definition and declaration of a variable which should make the DD gone.

I also tried to predefine the userAgent with the content from the catch but an empty catch is bad practice as well. Also findbugs just complains with the data flow anomalies just on different places...

So what would be a good solid way to prevent the findbugs reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be bad practice to silently *swallow* an exception.  However, I think the following code would be acceptable:

```
String userAgent = "volley/0";  // Default value
try {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    userAgent = packageName + "/" + info.versionCode;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException justUseDefaultUserAgent) {
}
```

For the second snippet, I would use a ternary conditional to emphasize the goal of assigning `stack` a value no matter what.

```
HttpStack stack = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) ? new HurlStack() :
    new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
```

Comment: Personally I don't like the ternary conditional and I just wanted to show where the userAgent is used for better understanding. Anyway it seems I will go with the empty catch and comment that it is intentionally left blank (tools like Sonar are complaining about empty blocks as well...)

Comment: If your tools are complaining about obviously valid code, making you contort your writing into a style that is arguably worse, then it's time to get better tools.